# How to highlight rows in a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jquery script to highlight DOM element on hover. But this script failed to highlight the rows of my table, there're no problem with cells.

In my script, I need to be able to select any type of elements, not just tables, so I cant't code a solution based on table selection, like [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for example.  Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('mouseover', function(event) {
    var highlightTarget = $(event.target);
    highlightTarget.addClass("highlight");

  }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    $(event.target).removeClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.main {
  border-top: 1px solid #9EBACF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #9EBACF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.cat {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9EBACF;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #9EBACF;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="main" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">data 1</td>
    <td class="cat">data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">data 3</td>
    <td class="cat">data 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">data 5</td>
    <td class="cat">data 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your highlight css. A js fiddle will be helpful.

Comment: Why not use `tr:hover`? Also, incorrect link for `JSFiddle` :-p

Comment: Edit : adding JSFiddle

Comment: @Rajesh : is there a generic solution, not only based on elements tests ? Because elements I hover can be div, li ... etc., all structured data elements.

Comment: What is your expected output when you highlight a `<td>` or an `<li>`?

Comment: No, there is no generic solution. If you log the `highlightTarget` to console, you see that the TR is never the target, the individual TD are. But now here you want to highlight not the element itself (TD), but the parent (TR) - whereas for other types of element you presumably do not want that behavior, but only highlight the hovered element itself? Now that is a _completely arbitrary_ decision you made here - so you will need to tell your script about it in one way or another.

Comment: You need to specify which elements you want to be highlighted. Otherwise, the element at the deepest level would get effected on mouseover. $('tr,li') for example could work.

Comment: @CBroe : you're absolutely right ! So I have to make test whereas I hover a td element or not. Tanks a lot !

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this using CSS would be to use the `:hover` selector.

```
.hoverable:hover {
    background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
}
```

All elements of class `.hoverable` will be highlighted. Note that in the following example, on hovering the first row, both `<tr>` and `<td>` are highlighted. In the second row, only the `<td>` is highlighted, while in the third row, only the `<tr>` is highlighted.

```css
.hoverable:hover {
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table class="main" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr class="hoverable">
    <td class="hoverable">data 1</td>
    <td class="hoverable">data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hoverable">data 3</td>
    <td class="hoverable">data 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hoverable">
    <td>data 5</td>
    <td>data 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, because I can't provide the underlying structure. I have to deal with an unknown structure.

Answer (score 0):

#### Logic

1. Bind mouse events on every element.
2. Create a map for elements where parent is to be considered.
3. Now, on hover, just check if map has value for this element type.
4. If yes, fetch parent selector and navigate to it.
5. If not, use current element as default element.
6. Remove class from any other element
7. Add class to stored element.

Note: step 6 is required because, you will have a `div`. This div will have a `table` and on till `td`, but you just want to access current element and not all.

#### Sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  createHover()
});

function createHover() {
  const map = {
    "TD": "tr"
  }
  $(document).on('mouseenter mouseout', '*', function(e) {
    var myClass = "highlight"
    var parent = map[this.nodeName];
    var $this = $(this)
    var el = $this;
    $('.' + myClass).removeClass(myClass)
    if (parent) {
      el = $this.closest(parent)
    }
    el.toggleClass(myClass, $this.is(":hover"))
    e.stopPropagation()
  })
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
.main {
  border-top: 1px solid #9EBACF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #9EBACF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.cat {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9EBACF;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #9EBACF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table class="main" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td class="cat">
        <strong>Edge case</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="cat">data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cat">data 3</td>
      <td class="cat">data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cat">data 5</td>
      <td class="cat">data 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <ul>
    <li>This is a test</li>
  </ul>
  <p>This is also a test</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Same as John Bupit : I have to deal with an unknown structure. Thanks.

Comment: underlying structure? Can you explain?

Comment: If I follow you, in the createHover function, I have to type the element that I will meet. But it's impossible, because I don't know them in advance. So like CBroe said, I just have to provide 2 cases : 1 for element with parent, like td, 1 for element without parent, like div or li.

Comment: @Didiermaccormick Please check the update. Note, this will have some performance impact

Answer (score 0):

you don't need JS for that, simple css hover would do it :

```
.cat:hover{
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

you dont need `.highlight` either